# Stop PHP PDO from clearing variables for each row fetch

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, pdo

I use HeidiSQL to write my PHP/MySQL queries. I want to use the following test SQL

```
SELECT @summer := 0, wrapper.* FROM
    (SELECT 
        bs_file.*,
        @summer := IFNULL(@summer,0), 
        @summer := @summer+1 as summer
    FROM bs_file  
) as wrapper
WHERE wrapper.summer = 3
```

to demonstrate my problem which sits in a much more complex query, where this scenario actually makes sense. This SQL basically increments `@summer` for each row.

The expected behaviour ist that the database returns the 4th row of my `bs_file` table plus some extra fields (0,2,3).

When I execute this query in HeidiSQL everything works as expected.

**BUT** when I work with PDO I will get nothing.

```
$sql = "SELECT @summer := 0, wrap...";
$connection->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

The `$result` returns false

I tried to use non-prepared statement, transactions. I know that you can change the connections attributes, but I don't know what to set to receive my result.

I found out that `@summer` will be set to `0` for every fetch of a row.

Comment: I ran your exact query in a PDO prepared statement and it worked correctly ;-/  code used: http://pastebin.com/UhgVx5jq

Comment: I originally used phalcon models an went down to pdo layer. Maybe I didn't try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know SQL that much to tell why your query doesn't work.
Neither can I reproduce your alleged result in mysql console.
And I highly doubt it's PDO to blame for clearing your variables.

Either way, I would do it in two queries, first setting the variable and then using in it the query

```
$pdo->query("SELECT @summer := 0");
$sql ="SELECT wrapper.* FROM
        (SELECT 
            bs_file.*,
            @summer := @summer+1 as summer
        FROM bs_file  
    ) as wrapper
    WHERE wrapper.summer = 3";
$row = $pdo->query($sql)->fetch();
```

This code works for me, whatever it means.

Comment: I don't think PDO is the problem, I think I'm doing something wrong configuring it. Two selects make no sense. the wrapper only nulls the @summer, because HeidiSQL keeps the state until the connection is killed.

Comment: There are numerous wrong statements in your comment above. Check your premises and come again.

Comment: Ok, I know what you mean, but your example still returns false in PHP instread of the third row as it does in HeidiSQL

Comment: For me it returns the third row. So it's not PDO but your query. Check your SQL.

Comment: Saved my day! I still don't get why this works, but it does when I split the request...

Comment: It should work. You can always run more than one query. other wise many database features just won't work.